# simple association works in console but not in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use a simple association to show user.email for workflows.

```
 def mail_notify_engineering
    @workflow = Workflow.where("Title like ?", "Engineer")
    @workflow = @workflow.first
    $temp1 = @workflow
    $temp2 = @workflow.user.email
```

When I run that, I get

```
NoMethodError in ApplicationController#notify_engineering
undefined method `email' for #<Workflow:0xb1ba8b8>

Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/product_development

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/mailers/application_mailer.rb:37:in `mail_notify_engineering'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:19:in `notify_engineering'
Request

Parameters:

None
```

However, if I run the commands in the console, it seems to work.

```
>> @workflow = Workflow.where("Title like ?", "Engineer")
  Workflow Load (3.0ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [pd].[workflows].* FROM [pd].[workflows] WHERE (Title like N''Engineer'')'
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Workflow id: 3, title: "Engineer", user_id: 1, created_at: "2016-09-02 18:28:29", updated_at: "2016-09-02 18:28:29">]>
>> @workflow = @workflow.first
#<Workflow id: 3, title: "Engineer", user_id: 1, created_at: "2016-09-02 18:28:29", updated_at: "2016-09-02 18:28:29">
>> $temp2 = @workflow.user.email
"christopher.mendla@ccttapes.com"
  User Load (2.0ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [pd].[users].* FROM [pd].[users] WHERE [pd].[users].[id] = @0  ORDER BY [pd].[users].[id] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int', @0 = 1  [["id", 1]]
```

The two models are:

```
class Workflow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'Workflow', foreign_key: 'user_id'

  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_presence_of :user_id

  validates_uniqueness_of :title, :scope => :user_id

end



class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workflows
```

The tables are

```
TABLE pd.workflows ( 
    id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
    title NVARCHAR(4000) NULL, 
    [user_id] INT NULL, 
    created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT PK__workflow__3213E83FA1246A13 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


TABLE tl.users ( 
    id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
    login VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    group_strings TEXT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    ou_strings VARCHAR(150) NULL, 
    created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    email VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    signature TEXT NULL, 
    operating_system VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    notes_path VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    client VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    outlook_path VARCHAR(150) NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT PK_users PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

If the association works in console, why isn't it working when run as an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `self_referencing` to `Workflow` model so

```
@workflow = Workflow.first
@workflow.user
```

will return you `Workflow` with `id = @workflow.user_id`

Change the association to

```
class Workflow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Rails will automatically search for `user_id` in `Workflow`